# Converting <canvas> linearGradient to CSS linear-gradient

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas, linear-gradients

I have this web tool that uses HTML Canvas to create linear gradients.  I want to convert those gradients to valid CSS gradients.  I tried everything I know of mathematics (which is not so much)... with no real results.

Things I now know:
- CSS linear gradeint CAN start from a negative value, where Canvas gradients can't.

Here's my current work:

```js
var width = 50;
var height = 50;

var handlesPositions = [
  {
    "x": 0.16,
    "y": -1.98
  },
  {
    "x": 0.84,
    "y": 2.98
  },
]

var colorStops = [
  {
    "color": "#FF0000",
    "position": 0.359
  },
  {
    "color": "#0094FF",
    "position": 0.495
  },
  {
    "color": "#FFFF00",
    "position": 0.652
  }
];


// CANVAS
var c = document.getElementById("source");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var x0 = handlesPositions[0].x * width;
var y0 = handlesPositions[0].y * height;
var x1 = handlesPositions[1].x * width;
var y1 = handlesPositions[1].y * height;

var grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(x0, y0, x1, y1);

grd.addColorStop(colorStops[0].position, colorStops[0].color);
grd.addColorStop(colorStops[1].position, colorStops[1].color);
grd.addColorStop(colorStops[2].position, colorStops[2].color);

ctx.fillStyle = grd;
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);


// CANVAS TO CSS
function canvasToLinearGradient(handles, stops) {
  const handle0 = handles[0];
  const handle1 = handles[1];

  const ydiff = handle1.y - handle0.y;
  const xdiff = handle0.x - handle1.x;

  const angle = Math.atan2(-xdiff, -ydiff);
  const cssStops = stops.map((stop) => {
    return `${stop.color} ${Math.round(stop.position * 100)}%`;
  }).join(', ');
  return `linear-gradient(${angle}rad, ${cssStops})`;
}


document.getElementById("current").style.backgroundImage = canvasToLinearGradient(handlesPositions, colorStops);
```

```css
#goal {
background: linear-gradient(172.19deg, #FF0000 -12.39%, #0094FF 48.06%, #FFFF00 117.89%);
}

.row {
  display: flex;flex-direction:row;justify-content:space-between;align-items:center;margin-bottom:10px
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 230px">
  <div class="row">Goal <div id="goal" style="width:50px;height:50px;"></div></div>
  <div class="row">Source <canvas id="source" width="50" height="50"></canvas></div>
  <div class="row">Current result <div id="current" style="width:50px;height:50px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: this may probably help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51884567/8620333 .. you will find some math there. Check the second part where you don't have to use background-size

Comment: @TemaniAfif Could not make it work. :(

Comment: ok will add an answer shortly

Answer (score 2):

As I explained in a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51884567/8620333) you can try to rely on the `background-size`/`background-position` to create the gradient.

First, here is how you can convert the first gradient to make the colors between `0%` and `100%` and easily handle it later with Canvas

```css
#goal {
  background: linear-gradient(172.19deg, #FF0000 -12.39%, #0094FF 48.06%, #FFFF00 117.89%);
}

#goal-1 {
  /*we add 12.39% to all to make the first one 0%*/
  background: linear-gradient(172.19deg, #FF0000 0%, #0094FF 60.45%, #FFFF00 130.29%);
}

#goal-2 {
  /*we divide by 1.3029 all to make the last one 100%*/
  background: linear-gradient(172.19deg, #FF0000 0%, #0094FF 46.39%, #FFFF00 100%);
}
#goal-3 {
  /*we increase the size by 1.3029 to rectify the previous division*/
  background: linear-gradient(172.19deg, #FF0000 0%, #0094FF 46.39%, #FFFF00 100%);
  background-size:130.29% 130.29%;
}
#goal-4 {
  /*we move the gradient to rectify the -12.39%*/
  background: linear-gradient(172.19deg, #FF0000 0%, #0094FF 46.39%, #FFFF00 100%);
  background-size:130.29% 130.29%;
  background-position:calc((-0.1239 * 50px)/1.3029) calc((-0.1239 * 50px)/1.3029)
}
#goal-5 {
  /*we can also wrote*/
  background: linear-gradient(172.19deg, #FF0000 0%, #0094FF 46.39%, #FFFF00 100%) calc((-0.1239 * 50px)/1.3029) calc((-0.1239 * 50px)/1.3029)/ 130.29% 130.29%;}


.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 230px">
  <div class="row">Goal
    <div id="goal" style="width:50px;height:50px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">Transition 1
    <div id="goal-1" style="width:50px;height:50px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">Transition 2
    <div id="goal-2" style="width:50px;height:50px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">Transition 3
    <div id="goal-3" style="width:50px;height:50px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">Transition final
    <div id="goal-4" style="width:50px;height:50px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">Transition final
    <div id="goal-5" style="width:50px;height:50px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now we can apply this logic to find our gradient. We already have the color stop. now we need to correctly find the size of the gradient which is the distance between the two points. Then find the background position.

Here is a first try where I added the background-size:

```js
var width = 50;
var height = 50;

var handlesPositions = [
  {
    "x": 0.16,
    "y": -1.98
  },
  {
    "x": 0.84,
    "y": 2.98
  },
]

var colorStops = [
  {
    "color": "#FF0000",
    "position": 0.359
  },
  {
    "color": "#0094FF",
    "position": 0.495
  },
  {
    "color": "#FFFF00",
    "position": 0.652
  }
];


// CANVAS
var c = document.getElementById("source");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var x0 = handlesPositions[0].x * width;
var y0 = handlesPositions[0].y * height;
var x1 = handlesPositions[1].x * width;
var y1 = handlesPositions[1].y * height;

var grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(x0, y0, x1, y1);

grd.addColorStop(colorStops[0].position, colorStops[0].color);
grd.addColorStop(colorStops[1].position, colorStops[1].color);
grd.addColorStop(colorStops[2].position, colorStops[2].color);

ctx.fillStyle = grd;
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);


// CANVAS TO CSS
function canvasToLinearGradient(handles, stops) {
  const handle0 = handles[0];
  const handle1 = handles[1];

  const ydiff = handle1.y - handle0.y;
  const xdiff = handle0.x - handle1.x;

  const angle = Math.atan2(-xdiff, -ydiff);
  const dist= Math.sqrt((y1-y0)*(y1-y0) + (x1-x0)*(x1-x0));
  console.log(dist);
  
  const cssStops = stops.map((stop) => {
    return `${stop.color} ${stop.position * 100}%`;
  }).join(', ');
  return `linear-gradient(${angle}rad, ${cssStops}) 50% 50%/${dist}px ${dist}px`;
}


document.getElementById("current").style.background = canvasToLinearGradient(handlesPositions, colorStops);
```

```css
#goal {
background: linear-gradient(172.19deg, #FF0000 -12.39%, #0094FF 48.06%, #FFFF00 117.89%);
}

.row {
  display: flex;flex-direction:row;justify-content:space-between;align-items:center;margin-bottom:10px
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 230px">
  <div class="row">Goal <div id="goal" style="width:50px;height:50px;"></div></div>
  <div class="row">Source <canvas id="source" width="50" height="50"></canvas></div>
  <div class="row">Current result <div id="current" style="width:50px;height:50px;"></div>
</div>
```

As you can see, we are almost good. The calculation of the position is a bit tricky and will need more in depth explication. will try to edit this later.