# Is it possible to set the gradient start and end positions in a CSS background similar to SVG start and end positions?

Tags: html, css, svg, linear-gradients

In an SVG gradient you can set the start x y and end x y position. Is it possible to do that in CSS.

Here is the original design:

[image]

Here is my SVG with linear gradient:

```css
.myRectangle {
 width: 331px;
 height: 137px;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<svg class="myRectangle">
  <linearGradient id="LinearGradientFill2" spreadMethod="pad" x1="1" x2="0.5" y1="0" y2="0.5">
    <stop offset="0" stop-color="#f7f7f7" stop-opacity="1" cssvalue=""></stop>
    <stop offset="0.266" stop-color="#ea0000" stop-opacity="1" cssvalue=""></stop>
    <stop offset="0.7685" stop-color="#6c165f" stop-opacity="1" cssvalue=""></stop>
    <stop offset="1" stop-color="#272020" stop-opacity="1" cssvalue=""></stop>
  </linearGradient>
  <rect fill="url(#LinearGradientFill2)" id="myRectangle" rx="0" ry="0" x="0" y="0" width="331" height="137">
  </rect>
</svg>
```

Here is my CSS linear gradient:

```css
#rectangle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(225deg, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(250,0,0,1) 27.59%, rgba(108,22,95,1) 76.35%, rgba(39,32,32,1) 100%)
}
```

```html
<div id="rectangle">

</div>
```

I've been referencing [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) on MDN and [this page](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#linear-gradients) on W3C.

The SVG contains the orientation of the gradient

`x1="1" x2="0.5" y1="0" y2="0.5"`

> The  element also takes several other attributes,
>   which specify the size and appearance of the gradient. The orientation
>   of the gradient is controlled by two points, designated by the
>   attributes x1, x2, y1, and y2. These attributes define a line along
>   which the gradient travels. The gradient defaults to a horizontal
>   orientation, but it can be rotated by changing these. Gradient2 in the
>   above example is designed to create a vertical gradient.
>   - from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Gradients

From other documentation:

> X and Y position of the start of the gradient line, as a multiple of
>   the object's bounding box: X=0 indicates the left edge of the bounding
>   box and X=1 indicates the right edge. The gradient line may start or
>   end outside the object's bounding box, so values may be < 0 or > 1.

Comment: in general or for this particular case? in general you will need some calculation

Comment: I can sort of get the angle and I can get the start and end position but neither is quiet right. I've added the original image to the post

Comment: guess what, I already answered a similar question with calculation detail: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51881307/8620333. Not about SVG but it can help since it's about two points that are defining the gradient

Answer (score 12):

You can divide all the value of color stop by the same factor in order to reduce the size of the gradient and make it similar to the SVG one.

I used CSS variable to make it easy but it's not mandatory

```css
.rectangle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  --s:2;
  background: 
   linear-gradient(225deg, 
    rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, 
    rgba(250,0,0,1)   calc(27.59%/var(--s)), 
    rgba(108,22,95,1) calc(76.35%/var(--s)), 
    rgba(39,32,32,1)  calc(100%/var(--s)));
}
```

```html
<div class="rectangle">

</div>

<div class="rectangle" style="--s:1.5">

</div>

<div class="rectangle" style="--s:3">

</div>
```

You can add an extra variable to offset the gradient which will simulate the starting point:

```css
.rectangle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  --s:2;
  --p:10%;
  background: 
   linear-gradient(225deg, 
    rgba(255,255,255,1) var(--p), 
    rgba(250,0,0,1)   calc(27.59%/var(--s) + var(--p)), 
    rgba(108,22,95,1) calc(76.35%/var(--s) + var(--p)), 
    rgba(39,32,32,1)  calc(100%/var(--s) + var(--p)));
}
```

```html
<div class="rectangle">

</div>

<div class="rectangle" style="--s:3;--p:20%">

</div>

<div class="rectangle" style="--s:3">

</div>
```

---

Here is some comparaison between SVG and CSS gradient:

```css
.rectangle {  
  background: 
   linear-gradient(var(--a), 
    #f7f7f7  var(--p), 
    #ea0000  calc(26.6%/var(--s) + var(--p)), 
    #6c165f  calc(76.85%/var(--s) + var(--p)), 
    #272020  calc(100%/var(--s) + var(--p)));
}

.myRectangle,
.rectangle {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<svg class="myRectangle" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <linearGradient id="LinearGradientFill2" spreadMethod="pad" x1="0.7" x2="0.5" y1="0.2" y2="0.5">
    <stop offset="0" stop-color="#f7f7f7"  ></stop>
    <stop offset="0.266" stop-color="#ea0000" ></stop>
    <stop offset="0.7685" stop-color="#6c165f" ></stop>
    <stop offset="1" stop-color="#272020" ></stop>
  </linearGradient>
  <rect fill="url(#LinearGradientFill2)"  rx="0" ry="0" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100">
  </rect>
</svg>
<div class="rectangle" style="--s: 3.82;--p: 23.87%;--a:213.69deg;">

</div>
<svg class="myRectangle" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <linearGradient id="LinearGradientFill3" spreadMethod="pad" x1="0.7" x2="1" y1="0.2" y2="0.8">
    <stop offset="0" stop-color="#f7f7f7"  ></stop>
    <stop offset="0.266" stop-color="#ea0000"  ></stop>
    <stop offset="0.7685" stop-color="#6c165f"  ></stop>
    <stop offset="1" stop-color="#272020"  ></stop>
  </linearGradient>
  <rect fill="url(#LinearGradientFill3)"  rx="0" ry="0" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100">
  </rect>
</svg>
<div class="rectangle" style="--s: 1.98;--p: 33%;--a: 153.5deg;">

</div>
<svg class="myRectangle" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <linearGradient id="LinearGradientFill4" spreadMethod="pad" x1="0.2" x2="0.5" y1="1" y2="0.8">
    <stop offset="0" stop-color="#f7f7f7" ></stop>
    <stop offset="0.266" stop-color="#ea0000"></stop>
    <stop offset="0.7685" stop-color="#6c165f" ></stop>
    <stop offset="1" stop-color="#272020"  ></stop>
  </linearGradient>
  <rect fill="url(#LinearGradientFill4)"  rx="0" ry="0" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100">
  </rect>
</svg>
<div class="rectangle" style="--s: 3.84;--p: 12%;--a: 56.3deg;">

</div>
<svg class="myRectangle" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <linearGradient id="LinearGradientFill5" spreadMethod="pad" x1="0.9" x2="0.2" y1="1" y2="0.8">
    <stop offset="0" stop-color="#f7f7f7" ></stop>
    <stop offset="0.266" stop-color="#ea0000" ></stop>
    <stop offset="0.7685" stop-color="#6c165f" ></stop>
    <stop offset="1" stop-color="#272020" ></stop>
  </linearGradient>
  <rect fill="url(#LinearGradientFill5)"  rx="0" ry="0" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100">
  </rect>
</svg>
<div class="rectangle" style="--s: 1.7;--p: 10%;--a: -74.05deg;">

</div>
```

You keep the color and percetange values the same. For the SVG you adjust x,y values and for the CSS you adjust the variables (the angle, the offset and the divider)

The formula of the angle is like below:

```
angle = arctang(Height*(x2 - x1)/Width*|y2 - y1|)
```

if `y2 > y1` we do an extra step to have `angle = 180deg - angle`

To find the divider we need to consider the length of the CSS gradient which is equal to

```
Dc = |Width * sin(angle)| + |Height * cos(angle)|
```

and the length of the SVG gradient which is equal to:

```
Ds = sqrt(Width²*(x2 - x1)² + Height²*(y2 - y1)²)
```

Then we do a simple division `Dc/Ds`

The formula of the offset `p` is `((Dc/2 - d)*100) / Dc` where `Dc` is the length of the CSS gradient defined previously and `d` is equal to:

```
d = (Width²*(x1-0.5)*(x1-x2)+Height²*(y1-0.5)*(y1-y2))/(sqrt(Width²*(x2-x1)²+Height²*(y2-y1)²))
```

---

Here is an interactive demo

```js
function update() {
 var H = $('[name=h]').val();
 var W = $('[name=w]').val();
 var x1 = $('[name=x1]').val();
 var x2 = $('[name=x2]').val();
 var y1 = $('[name=y1]').val();
 var y2 = $('[name=y2]').val();
 $('#LinearGradientFill2').attr('x1',x1);
 $('#LinearGradientFill2').attr('x2',x2);
 $('#LinearGradientFill2').attr('y1',y1);
 $('#LinearGradientFill2').attr('y2',y2);
 $('polyline').attr('points',(x1*W)+','+(y1*H)+' '+(x2*W)+','+(y2*H));
 
 var angle = Math.atan((H*(x2 - x1))/Math.abs(W*(y2 - y1))) 
 if(y2 > y1)
    angle=Math.PI - angle;
 $('.rectangle').css("--a", (angle * 180 / Math.PI)+"deg");
 var Dc = Math.abs(W*Math.sin(angle)) + Math.abs(H*Math.cos(angle));
 var Ds = Math.sqrt(W*W*(x2 - x1)*(x2 - x1) + H*H*(y2 - y1)*(y2 - y1));
 var s=Dc/Ds;
 $('.rectangle').css("--s", s+'');
 var d = (W*W*(x1 - 0.5)*(x1 - x2)+H*H*(y1 - 0.5)*(y1 - y2))/Math.sqrt(W*W*(x2 - x1)*(x2 - x1) + H*H*(y2 - y1)*(y2 - y1));
 $('.rectangle').css("--p", (((Dc/2 - d)*100) / Dc)+"%");
 
 // update elements
 $('[name=a]').val(Math.floor(angle * 180 / Math.PI));
 $('rect').attr("width", W);
 $('.rectangle').css("width", W);
 $('.myRectangle').css("width", W);
 $('rect').attr("height", H);
 $('.rectangle').css("height", H);
 $('.myRectangle').css("height", H);
 $('.myRectangle').attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + W + " " +H);
};

$('input').change(update);
update();
```

```css
.rectangle {  
  background: 
   linear-gradient(var(--a,0deg), 
    #f7f7f7  var(--p,0%), 
    #ea0000  calc(26.6%/var(--s,1) + var(--p,0%)), 
    #6c165f  calc(76.85%/var(--s,1) + var(--p,0%)), 
    #272020  calc(100%/var(--s,1) + var(--p,0%)));
}

.myRectangle,
.rectangle {
  width:150px;
  height:100px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:10px;
  border:1px solid green;
}

input {
 width:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
W: <input type="number" name="w" step="1" value="100">
H: <input type="number" name="h" step="1" value="100">
A: <input type="number" name="a" disabled>
<br>
X1: <input type="number" name="x1" step="0.1" value="1">
X2: <input type="number" name="x2" step="0.1" value="0.5">
Y1: <input type="number" name="y1" step="0.1" value="0">
Y2: <input type="number" name="y2" step="0.1" value="0.5">
<br>
<svg class="myRectangle" >
  <linearGradient id="LinearGradientFill2" spreadMethod="pad" x1="0" x2="0" y1="1" y2="0">
    <stop offset="0" stop-color="#f7f7f7"></stop>
    <stop offset="0.266" stop-color="#ea0000"></stop>
    <stop offset="0.7685" stop-color="#6c165f"></stop>
    <stop offset="1" stop-color="#272020"></stop>
  </linearGradient>
  <rect id="rect" fill="url(#LinearGradientFill2)" rx="0" ry="0" x="0" y="0" width="150" height="100">
  </rect>
  <polyline stroke="green" points="0,1 0,0 "/>
</svg>
<div class="rectangle">

</div>
```

<sup>The above gives perfect result when dealing with a square shape. For a rectangular shape there is still some difference. Checking the formula ...</sup>

Comment: KA... How are you getting the position factor? 1/x1=factor?

Comment: @1.21gigawatts actually it's a *trial & error* but I am thinking about the formulat to get the accurate value

Comment: @1.21gigawatts update the answer to consider a better and more generic way to calculate the gradient

Comment: Is it possible to get the gradient line from the x1, x2, y2 and y3 values?

Comment: @1.21gigawatts not easy, still trying to find the formula as it depend on the angle I guess. Will update if I find it.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts was able to identify the factor of division ;) only missing the third parametre now (the offset)

Comment: @Temani Afif Very comprehensive answer. I always read your answers with interest.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT thanks :) still missing a tiny piece of math to make it a complete one.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts it should be good now, I found all the formula and created an interactive demo at the end ... there is a slight difference between both result. Still not sure if it's rounding or something wrong in the calculation

Comment: Amazing! but some issues~! If the element size is a square the results are near exact match. But if the element is wide the gradient angle is off. For example, when the element is a square the x1,y1,x2,y2 make an angle of 225 degrees. But when the container is wide, say 300 x 100, the angle is 198 degrees. You can see this in the polyline. I think the gradient angle must stay the same whether the element is wide or narrow.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts no, the angle change based on the Width and Height because x,y are *a multiple of the object's bounding box* so if your increase the height or the width you will see a different angle for the same x,y.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes they are a multiple but the angle is unchanged whether wide or narrow. I will update with the view box and show a demonstration.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts I will recheck the formula again later, I probably missed something on the road

Comment: @1.21gigawatts by the way if you check the SVG gradient that we are not touching you will see that the CSS one is following it if we increase/decrease the width so technically the angle I am calculating is correct considering the SVG behavior

Comment: I've added images showing the gradient line in a square and a rectangle. I've kept the angle the same.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts Yes I understand what you meant but then the issue is the initial SVG because you don't have 45deg in the SVG gradient in your question.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts yes I noticed :) by the way I am still thinking about the calculation ... there is a tiny piece of math that I am still missing. The result isn't really accurate for rectangular shape and it has something to do with how SVG is dealing with the gradient. Let's hope I find it.

Comment: I'd like to preserve this answer because it's follows the positioning for SVG. I've added a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57617607/is-it-possible-to-set-the-gradient-in-a-css-background-using-unanchored-start-an.